# Timestamp to Instant in Java

Tags: java, time, timestamp, java.time.instant

> I have a pojo which has a filed type as Instant. I want to set the
>   Instant getting it from TimsStamp. Would it be possible?

For example: I have a `java.sql.Timestamp` which I want to convert to `java.time.Instant.` Would it be possible?

Comment: can you able to provide more description or code?

Comment: for example: I have a java.sql.Timestamp which I want to convert to java.time.Instant. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

we have ready have existing methods which covert Timestamp to Instant and vice versa.

```
    Instant instant = Instant.now(); // get The current time in instant object
    Timestamp t=java.sql.Timestamp.from(instant); // Convert instant to Timestamp
    Instant anotherInstant=t.toInstant();         // Convert Timestamp to Instant
```

Comment: I already have Timestamp object like 2016-07-14 09:00:0.0. I want this to get converted in to Instant object

Comment: timestampObject.toInstant();  we have method toInstant() in Timestamp class. and you can also see the 3 line of code

Comment: This instant is the instance of joda time not the java time so what you mentioned here did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[public Instant toInstant()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--)

> Converts this Timestamp object to an Instant.
>   The conversion creates an Instant that represents the same point on the time-line as this Timestamp.